# How to replay/show a saved flow in the console without triggering requests?

Tags: mitmproxy

The official docs [show me all the ways to replay or filter or transform flows](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/tools-mitmdump/), i.e. network data captures, but it does not show how to simply

So let's assume I save a flow via `mitmdump`, or – and I guess or rather hope – it is the same file, via `save_stream_file` (as an command-line option `--save-stream-file`).
Now can I can I load that again – *without* replaying, i.e. just to view it?

So think of a collected `dumpcap` file, I know I can load it in the wireshark GUI. Wireshark itself of course does not re-trigger the requests, just show them, so I can analyse them.

I want to do the same here. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Oh, it seems to be done with the `rfile` (or `-r` for short) option (not really an intuitive name, especially when the other option to filter that is called `readfile_filter`, i.e. not abbreviated).

Also, you do not want to bind a new proxy for that, so to do this, add `-n`. (This is another option that I could not find [being documented](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-options/), but remembered from some example)

So in the end, here is how to load it in `mitmproxy` e.g.:

```
$ mitmproxy --rfile ./mitmproxy-flow.cap -n
```

Comment: Asked follow-up question on how to load result live then, i.e. "follow" it: [How to continuously load a saved flow file from mitmproxy? (i.e. “follow”/-f the file)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63139637/5008962)