# How to continuously load a saved flow file from mitmproxy? (i.e. "follow"/-f the file)

Tags: mitmproxy

I've saved a file with the `--save-stream-file` (`save_stream_file`) option.

Now I want to replay that [as asked in my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63138629/5008962), but I want it to continuously follow the saved "flow".
How can I do that?

This is a follow-up question of [How to replay/show a saved flow in the console without triggering requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63138629/5008962).

Comment: Oh, [I've found a bug](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/1002) and it apparently once worked, but trying out the commands or using STDIN in v5.2 fails.

Answer (score 0):

After [some asking](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/1002#issuecomment-665189378) I got around and this should do the trick:

```
tail -f ./mitmproxy-flow.cap | mitmproxy --rfile - -n
```

Thanks to @mhils!

Though, at least for me, v5.2 [currently still has a bug where it crashes](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/4113).